DAX Expression for PBI
I have this 3 column (total wo, total ftf, product ftf %), I wanted to count the Binom.Dist using those 3 parameters. in excel you can simply put the formula of binom and fill in 3 paramaeters, but there is no direct way in pbi. after getting the binom, i wanted to get the average of that person product.
Product Group    | Total WO | Total FTF | Product FTF % | Binom.Dist | Average of Binom
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product 1        | 177      | 136       | 77            |            |
Technician 1     | 125      | 91        | 73            |            |
Technician 2     | 52       | 45        | 87            |            |
Product 2        | 37       | 30        | 81            |            |
Technician 1     | 21       | 16        | 76            |            |
Technician 2     | 16       | 14        | 88            |            |
Product 3        | 70       | 47        | 67            |            |
Technician 1     | 67       | 44        | 66            |            |
Technician 2     | 3        | 3         | 100           |        

I have slicer of technician, so the result should based on the technician selected.
This is what i have so far:
BINOM.DIST = IF([Total WO]=BLANK(),BLANK(),
IFERROR(DIVIDE(FACT([Total WO]),FACT([Total WO] - [Total FTF])*FACT([Total FTF])) * POWER([Accuracy-Product],[Total FTF]) * POWER(1-[Accuracy-Product],[Total WO]-[Total FTF]),0))

my expexctation is: for eg in the picture, i need to have the binom dist of the technician 1 , after that getting the average by (product1+product2/2)

Can you provide the expected result ?

I see that you are displaying your data as a matrix, can you provide your model ?

This link may be helpful.
